# How can I get the result of this triple Integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

$F_{z}=\iiint_{\Omega}  \frac{z-a}{\left[x^{2}+y^{2}+(z-a)^{2}\right]^{\frac{3}{2}}} d v$

$\Omega$:    `ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2, {x, y, z}]`

MMA code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2, {x, y, z}];
f[x_, y_, z_] := 
  \!\(TraditionalForm\`\((z\  - \ 
        a)\)/\((x^2\  + \ y^2\  + \ \((z\  - \ a)\)^2)\)^\((3/2)\)\);
Integrate[f[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, reg], 
 Assumptions -> r > 0 && a > 0 ]
```

(*$Aborted*)

Or,

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r];
f[x_, y_, z_] := (z - a)/(x^2 + y^2 + (z - a)^2)^(3/2);
Integrate[f[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, reg], 
 Assumptions -> r > 0 && a > 0]
```

(*$Aborted*)

Both of them can't get the result:

$- \cdot \frac{4 \pi R^{3}}{3}  \cdot \frac{1}{a^{2}}$

Comment: Recommendation:  Eliminate useless factors that have nothing to do with the problem, here $G$ and $\rho_0$.

Comment: Thanks, done. @David G. Stork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After switching to [the spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), Mathematica is able to crack it:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Integrate[t^2*Sin[\[Theta]]*(z - a)/(x^2 + y^2 + (z - a)^2)^(3/2) /. {x -> 
t*Cos[\[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], y -> t*Sin[\[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], 
z -> t*Cos[\[Theta]]}, {t, 0, r}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, 
Assumptions -> r > 0 && a >= -r && a <= r]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[-((4*a*Pi)/3), a > 0]`

```
Integrate[t^2*Sin[\[Theta]]*(z - a)/(x^2 + y^2 + (z - a)^2)^(3/2) /. {x -> 
t*Cos[\[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], y -> t*Sin[\[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], 
z -> t*Cos[\[Theta]]}, {t, 0, r}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, {\[Theta],0,Pi}, Assumptions->r>0&&a > r]
```

> `-((4 \[Pi] r^3)/(3 a^2))`

Maple 2021 confirms the former and  the latter.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @user64494